# How to remove this filesort?

Tags: mysql, indexing, filesort

I have problem, my slow query is still using filesort.
I can not get rid of this extra flag. Could you please help me?

My query looks like this:

```
select `User`,
       `Friend` 
from `friends` 
WHERE 
     (`User`='3053741' || `Friend`='3053741') 
     AND `Status`='1' 
ORDER by `Recent` DESC;
```

Explain says this:

http://blindr.eu/stack/1.jpg

My table structure and indexed (it is in slovak language, but it should be the same):

http://blindr.eu/stack/2.jpg

A little help is needed, how to get rid of this filesort?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth. The EXPLAIN is illegible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USING FILESORT` does **not** mean, that MySQL is actually using a file. The naming is a bit "unlucky". The sorting is done in memory, as long as the data fits into memory. That said, have a look at the variable [`sort_buffer_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size). But keep in mind, that this is a per session variable. Every connection to your server allocates this memory.

The other option is of course, to do the sorting on application level. You have no `LIMIT` clause anyway.

Oh, and you have too many indexes. Combined indexes can also be used when just the left-most column is used. So some of your indexes are redundant.

If performance is really that much of an issue, try another approach, cause the `OR` in the `WHERE` makes it hard, if not impossible, to get rid of `using filesort` via indexes. Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select "this is a user" AS friend_or_user, `User`, Recent
    from `friends` 
    WHERE 
         `User`='3053741' 
         AND `Status`='1' 

    UNION ALL

    select "this is a friend", 
           `Friend`, Recent
    from `friends` 
    WHERE 
         `Friend`='3053741'
         AND `Status`='1' 
) here_needs_to_be_an_alias
ORDER by `Recent` DESC
```

Comment: i modified query to dont use file sort and sorted it via PHP array :)

Comment: @RomanHolic - Use @fancyPants query.  It will be faster than your query + PHP !  `filesort` is _not_ the villain, it is the table scan; Roman avoids that !  You will need indexes starting with (friend, status, recent) and (user, status, recent).  Grrrr.

Comment: thank you for help, but when i am trying to execute fancypanths query it shows me ERROR "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"... do you know what is wrong pleasE?